# Publish Subscribe through all threads

Tags: android, publish-subscribe

Are there any Publish Subscribe libraries out there which broadcast events from each thread to all other threads?

For example, i'd like to send an event from a background thread/ AsyncTask/ IntentService whatever and catch handle it in the main thread.

Best

Comment: Try EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @Krish  Perfect, exactly what I've been looking for.